# Is it possible to install python packages in Node JS using python-shell package?

Tags: python, node.js, npm, pip

I just came to know that we can run Python scripts in Node JS using the below npm package.

[python-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell)

Is it possible to install python packages using the same library?
Something like `pip install package`

I need to import a few libraries to work with the Python scripts.

If it is not possible with this package, is there any other way to achieve it?

Comment: Just to clarify you want to install python packages using `python-shell` from node-js?

Comment: @Rahul yes. I'm new to this package, I'm not sure whether it is possible.

Comment: Why not install directly using `pip` on the terminal? or is it you want to incorporate into something?

Comment: @Rahul, I have a node app running on ubuntu server. Is it possible to run pip along with the Node app?

Answer (score 6):

Here's the first file : `test.js`

```
let {PythonShell} = require('python-shell');
var package_name = 'pytube'
let options = {
    args : [package_name]
}
PythonShell.run('./install_package.py', options, 
    function(err, results)
    {
        if (err) throw err;
        else console.log(results);
    })
```

This file runs another file `install_package.py` with arguments given to that file through command line.
You can get the package name from your HTML by using something like `document.getElementById().value()`

Here's the second file:`install_package.py`

```
import os
import sys
os.system('python3 -m pip install {}'.format(sys.argv[1]))
```

This install whatever package name was passed to it.

 As package `pytube` is already installed for me the output is:

```
rahul@RNA-HP:~$ node test.js
[ 'Requirement already satisfied: pytube in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (9.5.0)' ]
```

Same can be done using `subprocess` instead of `os`:

```
import subprocess
import sys
process = subprocess.Popen(['python3', '-m', 'pip', 'install', sys.argv[1]], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = process.communicate()
output = output.decode("utf-8").split('\n')
print(output)
```

Output using `subprocess`:

```
rahul@RNA-HP:~$ node test.js
[ "['Requirement already satisfied: pytube in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (9.5.0)', '']" ]
```

Hope this helps.
Comment if anything can be improved.