# Nodejs and python

Tags: python, node.js

Suppose I am making a nodejs module that I will upload in https://www.npmjs.com/.

And my nodejs module is using a python script and the python script using some modules that has to be installed using pip, right now my code is working because I have the python modules installed globally but suppose someone pulls my code who doesn't have python installed then I guess my js module won't work as intended.

### What should I do

Is there any hack around this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to install python packages in Node JS using python-shell package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56079548/is-it-possible-to-install-python-packages-in-node-js-using-python-shell-package)

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to install python from the npm package automatically.
For example, package [node-gyp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp) uses python and requires it as a dependency.